# Is it possible to use com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm working with GWT and Google App Engine...

I use  com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator to load dynamic Presenter-Classes on client-side.

It works when i test it locally. But not on google App Engine... :-(

```
PresenterFactory factory = (PresenterFactory) GWT.create(ReflectiveFactory.class);
IDynamicPresenter p =  factory.newInstance("ch...NewsPresenter");
```

this should bind the Class on runtime.

I implemented following code:
http://programmatica.blogspot.com/2007/10/classfornamefullyqualifiedclassnamenewi.html

Is it possible to use com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator on GAE?

Kindest Regards

Sam

Comment: I can't figuere the error out. I only get an javascript exception which says "umbrella exception" inside i found "ClassCast"-Exception.
I figured out that the ***.cache.html is different in firefox and IE. The Code for IE throws the ClassCast Exception, Firefox doesn't.

Comment: I compiled it without Runtime Class-Casting - than it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled it without Runtime Class-Casting - than it works!

problem was ClassCasting in IE-cache.html file

-XdisableCastChecking as Compiler Flag